# Use a table to create a calendar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So what is the deal with tables? Are they bad for SEO or is that just a myth? I'm creating a calendar for a company to advertise their fund-raising events. As a result, the contents of the calender need to be SEO friendly.

Is there anything wrong with using a table? Google Calendar uses a table, however, those a calendars are private and SEO doesn't enter it.

This calendar is on the front page of a website. It's a big deal. Are tables okay? Or should I try and create one with html?

I'm on bootstrap...is there an existing plugin that works well with it?

Comment: The problem with tables is that they were used to create the layout of pages. We should not use tables to create layouts. But if the data that you want to represent is better displayed as a table, there is no reason not to use a table. In the case of a calendar? I don't know, someone will advice.

Comment: you should use tables if you are storing data that looks best in a table. a calendar is a **great** example of when it's excellent to use a table.

Comment: Not necessarily. Calendars can be represented in many ways. In seven days blocks or as a list of days in a single column. What if I want to make a calendar with a 'flexible' display? So I can choose how to display it by changing my css. In that case I may consider a list, instead a table.

Answer (score 1):

Tables are absolutely fine... so long as they are used for tabular data, not for effecting a layout!

They are great for SEO, especially if you take care to markup them up with all the semantic goodness available to you:

```
<table summary="Interest Rates">
  <caption>Interest Rates</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Account Type</th>
      <th>Interest Rate</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Recommended for you: 'Young Saver'</td>
      <td>Interest from: 1.6%</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Smart</td>
      <td>From 2%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Young Saver</td>
      <td>From 1.6%</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

ref: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/tfoot

Note we provide a caption to summarize the table, we demarcate the various areas with a table header, table body and table footer, and we also markup out table header cells with `th`, not with `td` for normal data cells.

Comment: Yes, in your case is all honky dory, but what about a calendar? Should we use a table to represent a calendar?

Comment: I believe calendars are an example of tabular data, so they can be represented by a semantically correct html table.

Comment: I think we may be in a border line case here. Do you think that a calendar is semantically correct as a table of a weekly rows? Or as a list of days? What if I want to see it as a single column of days? You are representing the data as visualy is shown, in a table with seven columns, but I am not 100% convinced that is semantically correct. I dont say you are wrong, I only say it could be argued.

Comment: I'm with Raul here, it's been a decade. Any concrete answers?

Comment: The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22453548/11224924) linked [a link](http://phrogz.net/css/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html), containing [this](http://phrogz.net/css/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#tables) link which proposed 3 questions to determine whether a table should be used or not, one of them was "If I changed the order of the rows or columns, would it still make sense?". With a calendar, the answer to this question would be 'No', therefore **tables should not be used for calendars**. Credential: some guy named [Gavin Kistner](http://phrogz.net/resume)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe tables are bad for SEO, I don't think a specific code language or element could be bad for SEO. I would say give it a shot in divs first, as that would be the better way to do it.

[This link](http://phrogz.net/css/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html) might help you decide!

Comment: [The link](http://phrogz.net/css/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html), that was linked, contains [this](http://phrogz.net/css/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#tables) link which proposes 3 questions to determine whether a table should be used or not, one of them was "If I changed the order of the rows or columns, would it still make sense?". With a calendar, the answer to this question would be 'No', therefore **tables should not be used for calendars**. Credential: some guy named [Gavin Kistner](http://phrogz.net/resume)